# How to fetch these below values in python

Tags: python

I have a file in the below format

```
.aaa b/b
.ddd e/e
.fff h/h
.lop m/n
```

I'm trying to read this file. My desired output is if I find ".aaa" I should get b/b, if I find ".ddd" I should get e/e and so on.

I know how to fetch 1st column and 2nd column but I don't know how to compare them and fetch the value. This is what I've written.

```
file = open('some_file.txt')

for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    print (fields[0]) #This will give 1st column
    print (fields[1]) # This will give 2nd column
```

This is not the right way of doing things. What approach follow?

Comment: This is a confusing question. Are you trying to validate the contents of the file by asserting that `.aaa` is followed by `b/b`, `.ddd` followed by `e/e`, etc.?

Comment: i'm actually getting the value say".ddd" from some processing in my python script. This value also exists in this other file. So if this value exists in "some_file.txt" I want to get the space delimited right hand side value

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish. You're reading the file and printing out both columns. What is it that you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to do lookups, a dictionary is going to be your friend.

You could write a function to load the data into a dictionary:

```
def load_data(filename):
    result = dict()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            k,v = line.strip().split()   # will fail if not exactly 2 fields
            result[k] = v
    return result
```

And then use it to perform your lookups like this:

```
data = load_data('foo.txt')
print data['.aaa']
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you may want is to build a dictionary mapping column 1 to column 2. You could try:

```
file = open('some_file.txt')
field_dict = {}
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    field_dict[fields[0]] = fields[1]
```

Then in your other code, when you see '.ddd' you can simply get the reference from the dictionary (e.g. field_dict['.ddd'] should return 'e/e')

Answer (score 0):

Just do splitting on each line according to the spaces and check whether the first item matches the word you gave. If so then do printing the second item from the list.

```
word = input("Enter the word to search : ")
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        m = line.strip().split()
        if m[0] == word:
            print m[1]
```